# How to plot thermal noise in the time domain?

Tags: noise, signal-processing, thermal, signal-to-noise

The power of this thermal noise is given by:
P = 4kT (k = Boltzmann’s constant, T = temperature (Kelvins))

And, thus, the voltage by:

V^2 / R = 4kT (R = resistance)

Finally, we must take into account that this voltage follows a Gaussian distribution, with an RMS given by:

√4RkTB (B = bandwidth)

Comment: Random walk....

Comment: I would try to create such a plot in Matlab (or Octave which is the free clone of Matlab: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/ ). There are functions to create noise data directly. An FFT can be used to see the spectrum.

Comment: falstad’s also has a simple PRSG Noise source too. http://tinyurl.com/y4s43c5o so I added an LC filter

Comment: Read the book **Numerical Recipes** (it has hundreds of incarnations, but even the 1st edition which I have is adequate for this use.) In particular, they have a very nice and easy to understand section on using two uniform generators to produce a Gaussian distributed result. I've used the idea many times and it "just works right." All the usual tests will pan out okay. (Good uniform generators are better to use but even relatively poor ones seem to do okay from my testing.)

Comment: I did not realize this was cross-posted at the signal processing stack exchange. My answer is [there](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70026/41790). Also, kT is energy, not power, and the expectation value of thermal noise voltage is zero, as required by the second law of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a noise signal which you are sampling at sampling rate \$f_s\$. Then, your noise power becomes:
$$v_n^2 = 2kTRf_s$$
Here, \$2kTR\$ is the two sided Power spectral density (PSD).
With this background, you can implement the time domain thermal noise as follows (in MATLAB):

```
k = physconst('Boltzmann');
T = 290; % Room Temperature
R = 50; % Resistor Value 50 Ohms
fs = 1e6; % Sampling rate of 1MHz.
vn = sqrt(2*k*T*R*fs);
t = (1:1e7)/fs;
th_noise = vn*randn(1,1e7); % Time Domain Noise Signal
P_th = 10*log10(4*k*T*R);
figure(1);plot(t,th_noise);grid on;
xlabel('t (s)');ylabel('Noise Voltage (V)');
title(['Noise Signal with PSD ', num2str(P_th), 'dBc/Hz'], 'Interpreter', 'latex')
figure(2);
pwelch(th_noise,blackmanharris(length(th_noise)/8),[],[],fs,'onesided');
```

The output is as shown below, first one is the noise signal in time domain, second one is its PSD:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not the OP, but can you elaborate why it is $2k T R $ and not $4k T R$? I know the difference comes from one or two sided PSD, but how do I know that the two sided PSD is the correct one for thermal noise?

Comment: @Christian You can use either of two sided or one sided PSD and the noise power would come out to be the same. For two sided noise spectrum will be spread from \$-fs/2\$ till \$fs/2\$, so noise power will be \$2kT.(fs/2-(-fs/2)) = 2kTfs\$. For one sided PSD the spectrum is spread from 0 to \$fs/2\$, noise power will be \$4kT(fs/2-0) = 2kTfs\$.

Comment: Why does it go from 0 to \$f_s/2\$ and not to \$f_s\$? Is it because although you sample with \$f_s\$, the signal you "reconstruct" and therefore also the power only goes to \$f_s/2\$ due to the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem?

Answer (score 0):

I recall using that behavior, as part of Signal Wave Explorer (download is free) on robustcircuitdesign.com

Its been several years since I used random thermal stimuli. The Direct and Inverse Fourier transform (you select the length) are part of the tool's system modeling.